# My Dell Laptop starting in boot menu after My failled attempt to install Ubuntu and also I am not able to boot into windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, live-usb

I wanted to use Ubuntu. So I came across a way of using Ubuntu with a **bootable USB Stick** without installing it and I did that. It worked fine till now.

I enjoyed it so I thought why not Install it along with my existing Windows 10 which was working fine too.

**Now I made some partition as follows**

1. *I had **windows 10** in my C drive and E and F with some data in it*.
2. *I moved all the data from **E** drive to **F** drive.*
3. *Deleted E drive and made one **D** of 60GB and the rest a dynamic one named **E**.*

***Note: I didn't extend **C** because I had very less space there.***

*The partition looked something odd in the Ubuntu GParted with 4 sdas in dev and their size was not the way I had assigned in Disk Management.*
[image: My hard drive Partition]

I tried Installing Ubuntu making use of dev/sda3 which was empty:

I made-

One Ext4 as root.

One Swap Area.

One Ext4 as home.

I got EFI ERROR.

Made an EFI partition.

Again tried with an error **SWAP creation failed.**

Changed the boot priority to USB(Because I wanted to use Ubuntu by default).

**Now I am not able to boot into windows**

**I can still use Ubuntu live**

**All C Drive files are there**

Help! I can provide screenshots if needed.

Comment: *(...) and the rest a dynamic one named E*... The problem starts here. The Microsoft proprietary format isn't compatible/supported in Linux. And you don't create partitions for Ubuntu from Windows because you can't. Just leave unallocated space. Any partition create in Windows is either FAT, NTFS or exFAT and neither file system can be used to install a desktop Linux distro so the partition created in Windows would have to be deleted anyway.

Comment: Go to bios/uefi setup , and see if you have windows entry in boot option (or equivalent) ,  then change boot order as wanted. Sometimes press F12 or F9 early at boot is a shortcut for boot entries.

Comment: Looks like your NTFS partition containing Windows is the large one at the end of the disk. This is not a typical layout but in scenarios like this when you add partitions before the Windows partition it breaks the Windows boot process. It’s now the 4th partition and may have been the 3rd before. If that’s the case you can delete sda5 and it may boot again. I’ve seen this work before. Alternatively use Windows tools to repair it.